# how to save sql query result to csv in pandas

Tags: sql, pandas, dataframe, csv

I wrote a query in the data frame and want to save it in CSV file
I tried this code and didn't work

```
q1 = "SELECT * FROM  df1 join df2 on df1.Date = df2.Date" 
df = pd.read_sql(q1,None)
df.to_csv('data.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: ```df.to_csv('data.csv',index=False)``` and not ```q1```

Comment: Not working, and I edited it in the post @DeanTaler

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor',
this is the error message @SAL

Comment: Where is your connection? You need to specify the `con` argument.

Comment: I was writing the query in dataframe ,Because The data was in CSV file @Erfan

Comment: Basically you want to join two dataframes which are saved as csv?

Comment: Yes then save it to CSV @SAL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("Insert file path")
df2 = pd.read_csv("Insert file path")

df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'] ,errors = 'coerce',format = '%Y-%m-%d')
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'] ,errors = 'coerce',format = '%Y-%m-%d')

df = df1.merge(df2,how='inner', on ='Date')
df.to_csv('data.csv',index=False)
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Give me this error ValueError: "You are trying to merge on object and datetime64[ns] columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd. concat", Also I was tried to contact the data frames and didn't work, only the way was working is wrote SQL

Comment: I have updated the code. Can you check now?

Comment: not working and give me this message "AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values" @SAL

Comment: df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'] ,errors = 'coerce',format = '%Y-%m-%d')
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'] ,errors = 'coerce',format = '%Y-%m-%d')
df = df1.merge(df2,how='inner', on ='Date')
df.to_csv('data.csv',index=False)  @SAL this code running successfully ,Thank you